# How can I make the image disappear in Processing

Tags: image, processing

I'm using Processing 3.0.1 which is the latest version.

I successed to display the image when I pressed a certain key.

For example, when I press key 'a', then the image will be displayed.

I also want to make the image disappear when I press another key.

However, I can't find a way to do this.

If anyone knows how to do this, please help me

Here is the code

```
PImage Onepiece1, Onepiece2;
void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  Onepiece1 = loadImage("Onepiece1.jpg");
  Onepiece2 = loadImage("Onepiece2.jpg");
}

void draw(){
}

void showimage1(){
  image(Onepiece1,10,10);
}


void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'a'){
    showimage1();
  }
  else if(key == 'b'){
    // I want to make the image disappear when I press 'b'
  }


  println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this simple scenario @Majlik suggestion is ok, but usually it's not a good idea to draw in callback functions like `keyPressed()`. Instead use a flag to drive drawings in `draw()`, like:

**Untested**

```java
PImage Onepiece1, Onepiece2;
boolean showimage = false;

void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  Onepiece1 = loadImage("Onepiece1.jpg");
  Onepiece2 = loadImage("Onepiece2.jpg");
   background (255);
}

void draw(){
  background (255);
  if(showImage){ 
    showImage1();
   }  
}

void showimage1(){
  image(Onepiece1,10,10);
}


void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'a'){
    showImage = true;
  }
  else if(key == 'b'){
        showImage = false;
  }


  println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simple scenario like this you just need to redraw image with anything. Best practice is to use [background()](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html) function. So your reaction to pressing `b` could look like:

```
if(key == 'b'){
    background(99);
}
```

Also it is good practice to have specified same background color at the beginning inside `setup()` function:

```
void setup(){
  size(600,600);

  ...

  background(99);
}
```